# How to save file hash (md5) to database at upload resource file in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/file-fields.html

In this page described methods: `storeOriginalName()` and `storeSize()`.

But I also want save file hash to database.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

The md5 is saved in the parameter of the make() method.

```
        File::make('Attachment')
            ->disk('s3')
            ->storeOriginalName('attachment_name')
            ->storeSize('attachment_name'),
```

Will save the md5 in the column *attachement*, the original name in the *attachment_name* column and the size in the *attachment_name* column.